# Accessing a Dynamically Named array in jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I wish to name an array according to the table row containing the button that was clicked.

I get the table row thus:

```
var rowNum = $(this).parent().parent().index();
```

Now, I wish to name the array and access it.

```
var arrayName = 'arrTR' + rowNum;
window[arrayName] = new Array();
window[arrayName]["First"] = "Bob";
window[arrayName]["Last"] = "Roberts";
window[arrayName]["email"] = "me@there.com";

//The array should be accessible as arrTR__
alert(arrTR1["Last"]);
```

The alert does not work, so I am doing something wrong.

How should I refactor the code to allow me to update and access the array?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nwW4h/)

Comment: Don't contaminate the window object. Use jQuery's `data` method and store it in the `$.cache` if you want a global variable.

Comment: The fiddle you've provided works except that the fourth alert will only work if you've clicked the first row's button at some point to create the `arrTR1` variable. But why are you creating global variables like that? If you explain what you're trying to achieve somebody will suggest a better way. As an aside: don't use arrays with non-numeric properties, you should use objects: `window[arrayName] = {}`.

Comment: @Johan If not asking too much, would you mind updating your answer to show what you mean by using jQuery's `data` method and storing in the `$.cache`?

Comment: @gibberish When you're using the `data` method, jQuery uses the `$.cache` internally. So all you need to know is how to use the `data` method. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing with the dynamically named variables is essentially creating an array of those variables (one for each `rowNum`), but giving each of those array elements its own individual named variable.

There is a much better way to do this. Instead of generating a series of dynamically named variables, make a single array or an object. Then add an element or property for each of the dynamically named variables you were going to generate.

Your test code could look like this:

```
var arrTR = [];

var rowNum = 1;

arrTR[rowNum] = {
    First: 'Bob',
    Last: 'Roberts',
    email: 'me@there.com'
};

alert( arrTR[1].Last );
```

Alternatively, you can do something with `$.data` as mentioned in Johan's answer. But if you do use plain JavaScript code, use a single array as described here instead of multiple dynamically named variables.

There are several reasons to do it this way. It's cleaner and easier to understand the code, it may be faster when there are large numbers of entries, and you don't have to pollute the global namespace at all. You can define the `var arrTR = [];` in any scope that's visible to the other code that uses it.

Arrays and objects are made for keeping track of lists of things, so use them.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
$('.getinfo').click(function() {

    var result = $('table tr:gt(0)').map(function(k, v){
            return { 
                firstName: $(v).find('.fname').val(),
                lastName: $(v).find('.lname').val(),
                email: $(v).find('.email').val(),
            }
        }).get();

    //update to show how you use the jQuery cache:

    //1. set the value (using the body tag in this example):
    $('body').data({ result: result });

    //2. fetch it somewhere else:
    var res = $('body').data('result');

});
```

Not sure how you want to handle the first row. I skip in in this case. You can access each row by `result[index]`.

As you might have noticed, this saves all rows for each click. If you want to use the clicked row only, use the `this` pointer.

http://jsfiddle.net/nwW4h/4/

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code, and the only place it has error is the alert since it is not defined on the first click button

see this fiddle with a little update

```
if(rowNum === 1)
    alert(arrTR1["Last"]);
else if(rowNum === 2)
    alert(arrTR2["Last"]);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nwW4h/5/)